# XML search atribute with PHP GET

Tags: php, xml, html

I don't know how to create search engine in PHP where `$_GET['ID']` equal in XML tag atribute ID `<guest id="xx">` and extracts only data from the tag with special ID.

You do not know how to solve this problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<quests>
    <quest id="1">
        <ID>1</ID>
        <QUEST>Katakomby pod městem</QUEST>
        <INFO>Asi nevíte že pod naším krásným městem je spousta tajných chodem, které pořádně nikdo neproskoumal. Jsou tu již dlouhá staletí a údajně naši předci v nich ukryli zlatý poklad.</INFO>
        <TIME>780</TIME><!-- 780 - 13 minut -->
        <ITEMS1></ITEMS1>
        <XPMIN>180</XPMIN>
        <MONEY>800</MONEY>
        <LVL>1</LVL>
    </quest>

    <quest id="2">
        <ID>2</ID>
        <QUEST>Oprava zříceného mostu</QUEST>
        <INFO>Před několika dny strhla záplava starý dřevěný most u radnice. Pomoz jej opravit.</INFO>
        <TIME>7200</TIME>
        <ITEMS1></ITEMS1>
        <XPMIN>250</XPMIN>
        <MONEY>250</MONEY>
        <LVL>4</LVL>
    </quest>
.....And more<quest id="xx"></quest>...
</quests>
```

and I have no PHP code, it not function never.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This very esay with [SimpleXml](http://php.net/simplexml), this is a native php library for converting XML files to manageable objects.

For example:

```
<?php
    $xmlStringFile = "<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?><quests>....</quests>";
    $quests = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStringFile);

    if ($_GET['ID'] == $quests->quest[0]->ID) {
        echo $quests->quest[0]->INFO
    }

?>
```

Comment: Yea, it works! But "..->id" not. With "->ID" yes of course I need "id" this id <quest id="2"> == $_GET['ID'] {
echo "<QUEST><INFO>...";
}

Comment: well it's more or less like the id, just gonna aceder property info

Answer (score 0):

Use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) and [XPATH](http://php.net/domxpath):

```
$xml = 'your xml here';
$dom = new DOMDocument($xml);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xp->query("//quest[@id='{$_GET['id']}']");
$node = $nodes->item(0);
```